# I cant write in a html search box when i turn on a Three.js model

Tags: html, three.js

I have a `Search box` with some `css` properties, but when i load a 3d model with `Three.js`, my `Search Box` doesn't work any more, here is an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92RbX.png) to explain my issue.

When the model is on, i cant do anything with the `Search box`

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's hard to help. Create a basic [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) the demonstrates your problem

Comment: You could use [THIS](https://jsfiddle.net/2pha/ne7gjdnq/) as a starting point